# How to convert a decimal number to a binary number with fixed bits

Tags: vb.net, binary

I want to convert numbers from 0 to 15 like this:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
.
.
.
1111
```

The problem is that when we convert 2 to a binary number it gives only 10 in binary, but I want to convert 2 to 4-bit binary number 0010.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This code should do what you're looking for:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 15
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(4, "0"C))
Next
```

> 0000
>   
> 0001
>   
> 0010
>   
> 0011
>   
> 0100
>   
> 0101
>   
> 0110
>   
> 0111
>   
> 1000
>   
> 1001
>   
> 1010
>   
> 1011
>   
> 1100
>   
> 1101
>   
> 1110
>   
> 1111

The "2" in `Convert.ToString(i, 2)` means binary.  `PadLeft(4, "0"C)` means that if the string isn't four characters, append zeros to the beginning until it is four characters.

Comment: For i As Integer = 0 To 15
 Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(4, "0"c))
Next i

Comment: @m.qayyum: Thanks.  I found an online converter.  Glad it gave the right output ;)

Comment: Ya i also used c to vb converter ;)