# Convert decimal to binary in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, binary

I have been searching for a way to convert a decimal value to a binary string, but thus far have been unsuccessful. I have found many ways to convert an Integer to binary (*[How to convert a decimal number to a binary number with fixed bits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4048443/4801036)*, *[How to convert from decimal to binary .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21535919/4801036)* for example), but I want to be able to convert decimal values (2.5, 2374098.034286197548, etc.). Is there a way, or is there not a way to convert actual decimal values?

Comment: I don't know of anything built-in, no... would you want it as binary with a binary point, e.g. "10.1" for (decimal) 2.5?

Comment: I'm not sure how many Bits I would need for it but i was wanting it in Byte format binary (0000 0000, 0000 0001).

Comment: `Decimal.GetBits()` ?

Comment: Maybe i read the description of `GetBits()` wrong when I was researching, I'll look at that again.

Comment: I'm really not sure what that (0000 0000, 0000 0001) is meant to be for. You should edit your question to be *much* clearer...

Comment: I thought it was fairly clear with the integer conversion examples but I'll try to clarify. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to create a binary string for decimal values. Something similar to how a byte converts to an 8 bit binary string and a short to a 16 bit string and an integer to a 32 bit string and long to a 64 bit string.

Comment: I am struggling to see how this could be of any use. Is it just a proof of concept?

Comment: It's a combination of proof of concept for my sake and in the future I plan to use it for a data logger.

Comment: How do you plan to display the decimal places? What string would e.g. `18.91`?

Comment: I am assuming you are asking about precision? The displayed decimal will never be beyond 2 precision but the scale may vary. Values would likely range from 0.01 to 999.99.

Comment: @ARidder101 here you go **[Covert Decimal to Binary](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/109260)**

Comment: That one, like the 2 examples of what I don't want above, does not appear to support actual decimal values. It converts decimal format Integers. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is no real proper way to convert numbers with decimal positions (1.03, 234.65) so I decided to make something messy to work it out.

```
        Dim this As String = String.Empty
        For Each Match As Match In Regex.Matches(BoxyBoxington.Text, "\d+")
            If Match.Value.toDecimal <= Byte.MaxValue.toDecimal Then
                this = this + Convert.ToString(Match.Value.toByte, 2).PadLeft(8, "0") + NewLine
            ElseIf Match.Value.toDecimal <= Short.MaxValue.toDecimal Then
                this = this + Convert.ToString(Match.Value.toShort, 2).PadLeft(16, "0") + NewLine
            ElseIf Match.Value.toDecimal <= Integer.MaxValue.toDecimal Then
                this = this + Convert.ToString(Match.Value.toInteger, 2).PadLeft(32, "0") + NewLine
            ElseIf Match.Value.toDecimal <= Long.MaxValue.toDecimal Then
                this = this + Convert.ToString(Match.Value.toLong, 2).PadLeft(64, "0") + NewLine
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

This takes the numbers before and after the decimal separately and converts them based on the smallest integer type they fit into. This can then be saved as desired and converted back based on a reverse of your desired save method.

My custom extensions:

```
''' <summary>
''' Handles conversion of variable into Long Integer.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="X"></param>
''' <param name="I">Returned if conversion fails.</param>
''' <returns>Signed 64bit Integer</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<Extension> _
Public Function toLong(Of T)(ByRef X As T, Optional I As Long = 0) As Long
    Dim S As String = X.ToString
    Try
        If S = String.Empty Then
            Return I
        Else
            Return Long.Parse(S)
        End If
    Catch
        Dim result As String = String.Empty
        Dim ReturnLong As Long
        Dim Parsed As Byte
        For Each Character In S.ToCharArray
            If Character = "-" Then
                If S.Substring(0, 1).ToString <> "-" Then
                    result = Character + result
                End If
            End If
            If Character = "." Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If Byte.TryParse(Character, Parsed) Then
                result = result + Parsed.ToString
            End If
        Next
        If result <> String.Empty Then
            If Integer.TryParse(result, ReturnLong) Then
                Return Integer.Parse(ReturnLong)
            Else
                If Double.Parse(result) > Double.Parse(Integer.MaxValue.ToString) Then
                    Return Integer.MaxValue
                ElseIf Double.Parse(result) < Double.Parse(Integer.MinValue.ToString) Then
                    Return Integer.MinValue
                Else
                    Return Integer.Parse(ReturnLong)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Return I
        End If
    End Try
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Handles conversion of variable to Integer.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="X"></param>
''' <param name="I">Returned if conversion fails.</param>
''' <returns>Signed 32bit Integer</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<Extension> _
Public Function toInteger(Of T)(ByRef X As T, Optional I As Integer = 0) As Integer
    Dim S As String = X.ToString
    Try
        If S = String.Empty Then
            Return I
        Else
            Return Integer.Parse(S)
        End If
    Catch
        Dim result As String = String.Empty
        Dim ReturnInt As Integer
        Dim Parsed As Byte
        For Each Character In S.ToCharArray
            If Character = "-" Then
                If S.Substring(0, 1).ToString <> "-" Then
                    result = Character + result
                End If
            End If
            If Character = "." Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If Byte.TryParse(Character, Parsed) Then
                result = result + Parsed.ToString
            End If
        Next
        If result <> String.Empty Then
            If Integer.TryParse(result, ReturnInt) Then
                Return Integer.Parse(ReturnInt)
            Else
                If Double.Parse(result) > Double.Parse(Integer.MaxValue.ToString) Then
                    Return Integer.MaxValue
                ElseIf Double.Parse(result) < Double.Parse(Integer.MinValue.ToString) Then
                    Return Integer.MinValue
                Else
                    Return Integer.Parse(ReturnInt)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Return I
        End If
    End Try
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Handles conversion of variable to Short Integer.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="X"></param>
''' <param name="I">Returned if conversion fails.</param>
''' <returns>Signed 16bit Integer</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<Extension> _
Public Function toShort(Of T)(ByRef X As T, Optional I As Short = 0) As Short
    Dim S As String = X.ToString
    Try
        If S = String.Empty Then
            Return I
        Else
            Return Short.Parse(S)
        End If
    Catch
        Dim result As String = String.Empty
        Dim ReturnShort As Short
        Dim Parsed As Byte
        For Each Character In S.ToCharArray
            If Character = "-" Then
                If S.Substring(0, 1).ToString <> "-" Then
                    result = Character + result
                End If
            End If
            If Character = "." Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If Byte.TryParse(Character, Parsed) Then
                result = result + Parsed.ToString
            End If
        Next
        If result <> String.Empty Then
            If Short.TryParse(result, ReturnShort) Then
                Return Short.Parse(ReturnShort)
            Else
                If Integer.Parse(result) > Integer.Parse(Short.MaxValue.ToString) Then
                    Return Short.MaxValue
                ElseIf Integer.Parse(result) < Integer.Parse(Short.MinValue.ToString) Then
                    Return Short.MinValue
                Else
                    Return Short.Parse(ReturnShort)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Return I
        End If
    End Try
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Handles conversion of variable to Tiny Integer
''' </summary>
''' <param name="X"></param>
''' <param name="I">Returned if conversion fails.</param>
''' <returns>Signed 8bit Integer</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<Extension> _
Public Function toSByte(Of T)(ByRef X As T, Optional I As SByte = 0) As SByte
    Dim S As String = X.ToString
    Try
        If S = String.Empty Then
            Return I
        Else
            Return SByte.Parse(S)
        End If
    Catch
        Dim result As String = String.Empty
        Dim ReturnByte As SByte
        Dim Parsed As Byte
        For Each Character In S.ToCharArray
            If Character = "-" Then
                If S.Substring(0, 1).ToString <> "-" Then
                    result = Character + result
                End If
            End If
            If Character = "." Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If Byte.TryParse(Character, Parsed) Then
                result = result + Parsed.ToString
            End If
        Next
        If result <> String.Empty Then
            If SByte.TryParse(result, ReturnByte) Then
                Return SByte.Parse(ReturnByte)
            Else
                If Short.Parse(result) > Short.Parse(SByte.MaxValue.ToString) Then
                    Return SByte.MaxValue
                ElseIf Short.Parse(result) < Short.Parse(SByte.MinValue.ToString) Then
                    Return SByte.MinValue
                Else
                    Return I
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Return I
        End If
    End Try
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Handles conversion of variable to Tiny Integer
''' </summary>
''' <param name="X"></param>
''' <param name="I">Returned if conversion fails.</param>
''' <returns>Unsigned 8bit Integer</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
<Extension> _
Public Function toByte(Of T)(ByRef X As T, Optional I As Byte = 0) As Byte
    Dim S As String = X.ToString
    Try
        If S = String.Empty Then
            Return I
        Else
            Return Byte.Parse(S)
        End If
    Catch
        Dim result As String = String.Empty
        Dim ReturnByte As Byte
        Dim Parsed As Byte
        For Each Character In S.ToCharArray
            If Character = "-" Then
                If S.Substring(0, 1).ToString <> "-" Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
            If Character = "." Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If Byte.TryParse(Character, Parsed) Then
                result = result + Parsed.ToString
            End If
        Next
        If result <> String.Empty Then
            If Byte.TryParse(result, ReturnByte) Then
                Return Byte.Parse(ReturnByte)
            Else
                If Short.Parse(result) > Short.Parse(Byte.MaxValue.ToString) Then
                    Return Byte.MaxValue
                ElseIf Short.Parse(result) < Short.Parse(Byte.MinValue.ToString) Then
                    Return Byte.MinValue
                Else
                    Return I
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Return I
        End If
    End Try
End Function

<Extension> _
Public Function toDecimal(Of T)(X As T) As Decimal
    Dim s As String = X.ToString
    Try
        If s = String.Empty Then
            Return 0
        Else
            Return Decimal.Parse(s)
        End If
    Catch
        Dim result As String = String.Empty
        Dim ReturnDec As Decimal
        Dim Parsed As Byte
        For Each Character In s.ToCharArray
            If Character = "-" Then
                If s.Substring(0, 1).ToString <> "-" Then
                    result = Character + result
                End If
            End If
            If Character = "." Then
                result = result + Character
            End If
            If Byte.TryParse(Character, Parsed) Then
                result = result + Parsed.ToString
            End If
        Next
        If result <> String.Empty Then
            If Decimal.TryParse(result, ReturnDec) Then
                Return Decimal.Parse(ReturnDec)
            Else
                Return 0
            End If
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

It isn't very pretty, but I think it will work well enough for me.

Results of use:

> 100.13 - 01100100 and 00001101
>
> 52000.500 - 00000000000000001100101100100000 and 0000000111110100

It needs some work, but this is what I came up with. If anyone can find some improvements feel free to let me know.